# Is it possible to compare similarity scores across two word embeddings repository?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gensim, word2vec, fasttext

In my study, I am exploring if there is a statistically significant ideological bias in one set of media as compared to another. I was hoping to explore this using the word embeddings approach.

Let us take US and UK news media for example. If I build a corpora of all US media articles for a given time period and a separate corpora of all UK media articles for the same period, train them each using the same word embeddings algorithm (`gensim/word2vec/fasttext`) with the same set of parameters (e.g., window and vector size), is it possible to test if cosine similarity obtained between a pair of words in the US corpora is statistically significantly larger than cosine similarity obtained between the same pair of words in the UK corpora?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

your objective, approach and your question are unclear.

- Your objective is to discover any ideological biases if they exist
- You approach it by comparing two different outputs of the same word embedding algorithm (let's say Word2Vec)
- Your question is whether it's possible to compare two vectors trained from two different corpora

I will however just address your question. The answer is yes, of course it is possible to

> is it possible to test if cosine similarity obtained between a pair of words in > the US corpora is statistically significantly larger than cosine similarity
>   obtained between the same pair of words in the UK corpora?

How I would personally approach this is:

For each corpus do:

- get a random word
- get the 100 closest words to that word
- measure the average distance

do a p-test to test whether the difference in similarity among the words within the same corpora is significant.

Note however that, whether this will actually achieve your actual objective is not guarenteed.

Comment: thank you and sorry for the question ambiguity. I am not sure if I understood your approach. Let us say I am looking at 'equality'. We know that, in general, liberal-leaning ideology emphasizes equality more than do conservative ideology. My intuition is that cosine similarity between man and woman must be higher in the former than latter. Let us say I get 0.7 and 0.4 as scores from these two corpora. How do I test whether the difference of 0.3 betwen the two corpora is statistically significant?